# event.target.setVolume(0); doesn't work by itself, why?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, youtube-api, dom-events

```
event.target.setVolume(0); // doesn't work by itself
```

In fact, in the next line

```js
t.getVolume(); // spits 100, always
```

But when it is placed inside an event handler, it does. Why?

```
scroll.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) { changeVolume(e, this) });
    function changeVolume(event, el)
    {
        const dir = Math.sign(event.deltaY) * -1;
        const parsed = parseInt(el.value, 10);
        const value = Number(dir + parsed);
        t.setVolume(value); // TARGET
        // OH wait! Now - it does work. Why?
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the iframe needs to be loaded to change -this-one-property-, everything else works fine - set - get - : PlaybackRate, sekto, unMute, mute... EVERYTHING!!

Within the target **proto**: store a closure with the desired volume and protect yourself with a guard clause.

```js
function onPlayerReady(event)
{
    const t = event.target;

    function printVol()
    {
        console.log(
            {
                getVol: t.getVolume(), //nope
                volume: t.__proto__.newVol
            }
        );
    }
    function readyToChangeVolumeOnce()
    {
        if (!t.__proto__.changedVolumeOnce)
        {
            t.__proto__.changedVolumeOnce = true;
            t.setVolume(t.__proto__.newVol);
            printVol(); // works as expected... right. Should I be doing this?
        }
    }

    // javascript is crazy
    t.__proto__.changedVolumeOnce = false;
    t.__proto__.readyToChangeVolumeOnce = readyToChangeVolumeOnce;
    t.__proto__.newVol = validVolume(); // 20 for example
}
```

Once the iframe (API) knows it's alright to play, then call the function inside the **proto**.

```js
function onStateChange(state)
{
    const t = state.target;
    if (state.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
    {
       t.__proto__.readyToChangeVolumeOnce(); //man...
    }
}
```

It's a workaround, I don't think it is an answer per se. I'm happy it works though.
I also noticed that `t.unmute()` assigns a low volume if the volume was `0`.
Again, everybody, all of this could be a MAJOR misunderstanding form my end. I don't know.